# Setting up pie charts subplots with an appropriate size and spacing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I'm struggling setting up pie chart subplots with an appropriate size and spacing.
If the size of a pie chart is to small then the data is not visible, if the spacing between subplots is not appropriate then the graph will be crammed up.
So the layout of the subplots is the following 3 rows; 2 columns.
Please see below snippet from the dataset:

```
violent_main=pd.DataFrame({'Counts': crimes[crimes['Class Main Cathegory'].notnull()==True].groupby(['Police District Number'])['Class Main Cathegory'].value_counts()}).reset_index()
violent_main
```

Also attached print screen of dataset:
[image: dataset snippet]

I'm using the following code to plot:

```
#PD_1D
label_PD_1D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='1D']['Class Main Cathegory']
values_PD_1D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='1D']['Counts']

#PD_2D
label_PD_2D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='2D']['Class Main Cathegory']
values_PD_2D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='2D']['Counts']

#PD_3D
label_PD_3D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='3D']['Class Main Cathegory']
values_PD_3D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='3D']['Counts']

#PD_4D
label_PD_4D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='4D']['Class Main Cathegory']
values_PD_4D=violent_main[violent_main['Police District Number']=='4D']['Counts']

fig = {
  "data": [
    {
      "values": values_PD_1D,
      "labels": label_PD_1D,
      "domain": {'x': [0.0, 0.35], 'y': [2.22, 2.53]},
      "name": "PD_1D",
      "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,  
      "type": "pie"
    },     
    {
      "values": values_PD_2D,
      "labels": label_PD_2D,
      "text":"CO2",
      "textposition":"inside",
      "domain":{'x': [0.50, 0.85], 'y': [2.22, 2.53]},
      "name": "PD_2D",
      "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,  
      "type": "pie"
    },
     {
      "values": values_PD_3D,
      "labels": label_PD_3D,
      "text":"CO2",
      "textposition":"inside",
      'domain': {'x': [0.0, 0.35], 'y': [.9, 1.13]},
      "name": "CO2 Emissions",
      "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,   
      "type": "pie"
    }  
  ],
  "layout": {
        "title":"Violent Crimes by main cathegory",
        "annotations": [
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 20
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "PD_1D",
                "x": 0.12,
                "y": 0.5
            },
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 20
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "PD_2D",
                "x": 0.73,
                "y": 0.5
                },
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 20
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "PD_3D",
                "x": 0.20,
                "y": 0.25
                }
            ]
        }
    }
iplot(fig, filename='donut')
```

Within this code I'm trying to manipulate layout using the "domain":{x:[],y:[])
However I can't the layout desired. So for instance plot number 3 is smaller and above plot 1 and plot 2. What I would like is that plot to be the same size as the other plots but below then
Please see below plot:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K7p8.png)

I'm hoping I can figure out the logic so I can plot the pie charts: 3 rows: 2 columns.
Please advise

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Maximilian this is not what I was looking for, but I managed to solve the issue. This can be closed

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this excellent answer: [How to plot pie charts as subplots with custom size with Plotly in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629735/how-to-plot-pie-charts-as-subplots-with-custom-size-with-plotly-in-python)

In order to get identically size plots their `domain` spans need to be identical. The domains starts from the bottom (e.g. 0 is down, 1 is up).

[image]
    values_PD_1D = [i for i in range(30, 100, 10)]
    values_PD_2D = values_PD_1D[::-1]
    values_PD_3D = values_PD_1D[::-2]

```
label_PD_1D = ['Javascript', 'Python', 'R', 'Java', 'C#', 'C++', 'Perl']
label_PD_2D = label_PD_1D
label_PD_3D = label_PD_1D[::-2]

fig = {
  "data": [
    {
      "values": values_PD_1D,
      "labels": label_PD_1D,
      "domain": {'x': [0.0, 0.45], 'y': [0, 0.45]},
      "name": "PD_1D",
      "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,  
      "type": "pie"
    },     
    {
      "values": values_PD_2D,
      "labels": label_PD_2D,
      "textposition":"inside",
      "domain":{'x': [0.55, 1], 'y': [0, 0.45]},
      "name": "PD_2D",
      "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,  
      "type": "pie"
    },
     {
      "values": values_PD_3D,
      "labels": label_PD_3D,
      'domain': {'x': [0.0, 0.45], 'y': [0.55, 1]},
      "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,   
      "type": "pie"
    }  
  ],
  "layout": {
        "title":"Programming languages",
        "annotations": [
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 20
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "PD_1D",
                "x": 0.12,
                "y": 0.5
            },
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 20
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "PD_2D",
                "x": 0.73,
                "y": 0.5
                },
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 20
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "PD_3D",
                "x": 0.12,
                "y": 1.1
                }
            ]
        }
    }

plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='donut')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted can be achieved by using a layout dictionary like this:

```
layout = dict(height = 1200,
              width = 1000,
              autosize = False,
              title = 'Violent Crimes/PD by main cathegory',
              annotations= [{"font": {"size": 24},"showarrow": False,"text": "PD_1D","x": 0.14, "y": 0.82},
                            {"font": {"size": 24},"showarrow": False,"text": "PD_2D","x": 0.86, "y": 0.82},
                            {"font": {"size": 24},"showarrow": False,"text": "PD_3D","x": 0.14, "y": 0.48},
                            {"font": {"size": 24},"showarrow": False,"text": "PD_4D","x": 0.86, "y": 0.48},
                            {"font": {"size": 24},"showarrow": False,"text": "PD_5D","x": 0.14, "y": 0.13},
                            {"font": {"size": 24},"showarrow": False,"text": "PD_6D","x": 0.86, "y": 0.13}]

              )
```

In the layout dictionary the width,height parameters control subplots size. 
x,y domains serve more of a starting point for each subplot and are bound to a upper limit of 1. So you can't a good level of detail and spacing between subplots using only the domains.
See attached print screen
[Pie chart with appropriate size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InGZa.png)

Comment: We don't "close" answered questions; instead, you should [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that it is useful for others in the future.