# Plotting multiple pie charts in plotly

Tags: python-2.7, plotly

I have the following code from edited from: [How to plot pie charts as subplots with custom size with Plotly in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629735/how-to-plot-pie-charts-as-subplots-with-custom-size-with-plotly-in-python)

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500,2500,1053,500]
domains = [
    {'x': [0.0, 0.33], 'y': [0.0, 0.50]},
    {'x': [0.33, 0.66], 'y': [0.0, 0.50]},
    {'x': [0.66, 1], 'y': [0.0, 0.50]},
    {'x': [0.0, 0.33], 'y': [0.50, 1]},
    {'x': [0.33, 0.66], 'y': [0.50, 1]},
    {'x': [0.66, 1], 'y': [0.50, 1]},
]
traces = []
valueslist = []

for domain in domains:
    trace = go.Pie(labels = labels,
                   values = values,
                   domain = domain)
    traces.append(trace)

layout = go.Layout(height = 600,
                   width = 600,
                   autosize = False,
                   title = 'Main title')
fig = go.Figure(data = traces, layout = layout)
py.iplot(fig, show_link = False, image='png')
```

I am trying to plot 6 pie charts at one time with *different values* and *different titles* for each chart. How should I add these extra lists? Assume, I have the following lists to add:

```
values1 = [5, 6, 1, 2]
values2 = [1, 4, 5, 6]
values3 = [2, 6, 2, 4]
values4 = [1, 5, 3, 7]
values5 = [25, 51, 33, 47]
#with following titles:
title = 'title0'
title1 = 'title1'
title2 = 'title2'
title3 = 'title3'
title4 = 'title4'
title5 = 'title5'
```

Comment: You could put your `values1-6` in another `list`, e.g. called `values`, loop over the `domains` by using iterate and use `values = values[index]`

Comment: That is what I thought first, but, how about titles?

Comment: Use suplots: https://plot.ly/python/subplots/

Comment: Initially, I tried to use it. It yields the following error: PlotlyDictKeyError: 'xaxis' is not allowed in 'pie'

Path To Error: ['xaxis']

Valid attributes for 'pie' at path [] under parents []: